# User, it's roles and relationship in light of REST protocol

Tags: mysql, sql, rest, uri, naming-conventions

### user

```
id, username
1, 'john'
2, 'joe'
```

### role

```
id, name
1, 'admin'
2, 'accounts'
3, 'finance'
4, 'marketing'
5, 'support'
```

### user_role

```
user_id, role_id
1,       1
1,       2
2,       1
```

---

REST convention and effects, Please review each call and associated action and if someone can explain the right thing to do for each kind of call. I'm using MySQL.

**Question**

I'm confused with `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH`. My question is what kind of SQL query would go with each call, provided some as an example. I'd understand better with an SQL Query and some description.

**POST:**

```
POST /users/1/roles
body: {id: 2}

INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES(1, 2);
```

Insert role #2 to the user. I think I've to be sure on the client end that role#2 is not existing already before I call it.

---

**PUT: (Insert or Update???)**

```
PUT /users/1/roles
body: [2, 3, 4]

DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = 1; 
INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4);
```

Replace all roles with new representation, i.e. will delete any existing roles the user might have and update it with new roles provided.

Another scenario of PUT where it both creates or update (UPSERT), username is unique index.

```
PUT /users
body {username: 'joe'}

INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES('joe')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET username = VALUES(username);
```

---

**PATCH** (partial update)

```
PATCH /users/1/roles
body: [3, 4, 5]

DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = 1 AND role_id NOT IN (3, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = VALUES(user_id), role_id = VALUES(role_id);
```

Delete any existing relations that user#1 has and are not 4, 5, 7, and then UPSERT these roles.

---

**DELETE**

```
DELETE /users/1/roles
DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Delete all roles of a user#1

```
DELETE /users/1/roles/2
DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = 1 and role_id = 2;
```

Delete role#2 of user#1

Comment: What you are describing here is just CRUD. I think your misunderstood what REST is. There can be mapping between database entities and REST resources, but this is not mandatory.

Comment: Please enlighten more

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture REST is in the presentation tier while your SQL is in the data tier. There is no direct connection between them. E.g. you can replace REST to SOAP without changing the SQL code, or you can replace the SQL database with a noSQL database without changing the REST specific code.

Comment: but isn't that this REST presentation layer dictates some specific task to be done, to the data layer?

Comment: The specific task is done in the logic tier, and not in the data tier. The logic tier can use the data tier to accomplish some of the sub-tasks. The REST hyperlinks are mapped to the operations of the logic tier and not to the entities of the data tier. E.g. I can create a REST API, which does not even have a data tier, just a logic tier.

Comment: so it's a sub effect, that's what I'm figuring out, the waterfall effect of REST to logic layer to data tier